# * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> E:Android10\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
> import org.apache.cordova.Whitelist;
> ^
> symbol:   class Whitelist
> location: package org.apache.cordova
> E:Android10\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:769: error: cannot find symbol
> Whitelist whitelist = (Whitelist)gwl.invoke(webView);
> ^
> symbol:   class Whitelist
> location: class org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer
> E:\Android10\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java:769: error: cannot find symbol
> Whitelist whitelist = (Whitelist)gwl.invoke(webView);
> ^
> symbol:   class Whitelist
> location: class org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer
> Note: E:\Android10\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: E:\Android10\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> 3 errors

Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 10.0.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, (and 25 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.1
native-run (update available: 1.4.0)   : 1.0.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (D:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)
NodeJS            : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 6.14.8
OS                : Windows 10

We are trying to build failure getting this errors. please help me !

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use cordova-plugin-file-transfer in Cordova 10 which causes the build issue. **Cordova-plugin-file-transfer** is not working with Cordova Android 10 anymore because Whitelist was renamed to Allowlist.

Please refer to the github issue: [Github Issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/issues/306)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the import package name

```
from android.support.annotation to androidx.annotation 

e.g - import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi; 
to  - import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
```

by using AndroidX libs (check android.useAndroidX=true in gradle.properties) in IonicWebViewEngine.java